# Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s) when Vector goes out of scope

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I have written a box car filter on binary image data using C++ vectors.

The program runs successfully and I get all the required output without any issue. But, when the code exits, i.e., when the vector variable goes out of scope, I get a segmentation fault.

I got the same issue when I closed/cleared the vector in the end of loop using `erase`, `clear`, `vector<vector<float> >().swap` etc.

I also tried running the code in a separate function, where the vector goes out of scope automatically, and the program dumps memory right after processing single image. (each loop processes one image)

---

Complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void createhdr(string,int,int);

void avg(string,string,int,int,string);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc < 5) {
        cerr<<"1. Input Path"<<endl;
        cerr<<"2. Rows"<<endl;
        cerr<<"3. Cols"<<endl;
        cerr<<"4. Out Path"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    string in_path(argv[1]);

    int rows = stoi(argv[2]);
    int cols = stoi(argv[3]);

    vector<string> C3_files;
    C3_files.emplace_back("C12_Real");   
    C3_files.emplace_back("C11");   
    C3_files.emplace_back("C12_Imag");   
    C3_files.emplace_back("C13_Real");   
    C3_files.emplace_back("C13_Imag");   
    C3_files.emplace_back("C22");   
    C3_files.emplace_back("C23_Real");   
    C3_files.emplace_back("C23_Imag");   
    C3_files.emplace_back("C33");

    for(auto vec: C3_files) {
       cout<<vec<<endl;
    }

    string out_path(argv[4]);

    cout<<"Inpath: "<<in_path<<endl;
    cout<<"Outpath: "<<out_path<<endl<<endl<<endl;

    vector<vector<float> > c;
    vector<vector<float> > C3;
        c = vector<vector<float> >(rows,vector<float>(cols,0.0f));
        C3 = vector<vector<float> >(rows,vector<float>(cols,0.0f));
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        cout<<"File "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
        string inpath = in_path+"/"+C3_files[i]+".bin";
        string outpath = out_path+"/"+C3_files[i]+".bin";
        string hdrpath = out_path+"/"+C3_files[i];
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        ifstream c_f;
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        ofstream C_f;
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        c_f.open(inpath,ios::in|ios::binary);
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        C_f.open(outpath,ios::out|ios::binary);
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        cout<<"Inpath: "<<inpath<<endl;
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        cout<<"Outpath: "<<outpath<<endl;
        cout<<"*"<<endl;

        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        c_f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&c[0][0]),rows*cols*sizeof(float));
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        cout<<"Calculating ensemble average."<<flush;
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
                int sum = 0;
                int win = 3;

                for(int p = -win/2; p < win/2; p++) {
                    int index_x = j + p;
                    for(int q = -win/2; q < win/2; q++) {
                        int index_y = k + q;
                        if(index_x < 0 || index_y < 0 || index_x >= rows || index_y >= cols) {
                            sum +=0;
                        }
                        else {
                            sum += c[index_x][index_y];
                        }
                    }
                }
                C3[j][k] = sum;
            }
        }
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        cout<<"done."<<endl;
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        C_f.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&C3[0][0]),rows*cols*sizeof(float));
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        createhdr(hdrpath,cols,rows);
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        c_f.close();
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        C_f.close();
        cout<<"*"<<endl;
        // vector<vector<float> >(rows,vector<float>(cols,0.0f)).swap(c);
        // vector<vector<float> >(rows,vector<float>(cols,0.0f)).swap(C3);
        // avg(inpath,outpath,rows,cols,hdrpath);
    }
    c.clear();
    cout<<"Meh!"<<endl;
    cout<<"That's all folks!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void avg(string inpath, string outpath, int rows, int cols, string hdrpath)
{
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    ifstream c_f;
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    ofstream C_f;
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    c_f.open(inpath,ios::in|ios::binary);
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    C_f.open(outpath,ios::out|ios::binary);
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    cout<<"Inpath: "<<inpath<<endl;
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    cout<<"Outpath: "<<outpath<<endl;
    cout<<"*"<<endl;

    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    vector<vector<float> > c = vector<vector<float> >(rows,vector<float>(cols,0.0f));
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    c_f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&c[0][0]),rows*cols*sizeof(float));
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    vector<vector<float> > C3 = vector<vector<float> >(rows,vector<float>(cols,0.0f));
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    cout<<"Calculating ensemble average."<<flush;
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
            int sum = 0;
            int win = 3;

            for(int p = -win/2; p < win/2; p++) {
                int index_x = j + p;
                for(int q = -win/2; q < win/2; q++) {
                    int index_y = k + q;
                    if(index_x < 0 || index_y < 0 || index_x >= rows || index_y >= cols) {
                        sum +=0;
                    }
                    else {
                        sum += c[index_x][index_y];
                    }
                }
            }
            C3[j][k] = sum;
        }
    }
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    cout<<"done."<<endl;
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    C_f.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&C3[0][0]),rows*cols*sizeof(float));
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    createhdr(hdrpath,cols,rows);
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    c_f.close();
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
    C_f.close();
    cout<<"*"<<endl;
}

void createhdr(string filename, int samples, int scans)
{
        ofstream hdr(string(filename+".hdr"));

        hdr<<"ENVI"<<endl;
        hdr<<"description = {"<<endl;
        hdr<<"    File Imported into ENVI.}"<<endl;
        hdr<<"samples = "<<samples<<endl;
        hdr<<"lines = "<<scans<<endl;
        hdr<<"bands = 1"<<endl;
        hdr<<"header offset = 0"<<endl;
        hdr<<"file type = ENVI standard"<<endl;
        hdr<<"data type = 4"<<endl;
        hdr<<"interleave = bsq"<<endl;
        hdr<<"sensor type = Unknown"<<endl;
        hdr<<"byte order = 0"<<endl;
        hdr<<"wavelenfth units = Unknown";

        hdr.close();
        cout<<"HDR file created."<<endl;
}
```

Valgrind output

```
==3505== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3505== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3505== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3505== Command: ./C3_Boxcar.o /home/tarun/Documents/Work/Data/10Dec2019/extract/ML/scaled/C3 12087 512 /home/tarun/Documents/Work/Data/10Dec2019/extract/ML/scaled/C3/C3_BoxCar
==3505== Parent PID: 3056
==3505== 
==3505== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==3505==    at 0x54C9230: __read_nocancel (syscall-template.S:84)
==3505==    by 0x4EEA216: std::__basic_file<char>::xsgetn(char*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==3505==    by 0x4F24C08: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==3505==    by 0x4F318EA: std::istream::read(char*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==3505==    by 0x4022F3: main (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==  Address 0x5aff4a0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2,048 alloc'd
==3505==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3505==    by 0x405673: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x405456: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<float> >::allocate(std::allocator<float>&, unsigned long) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x4050ED: std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x404C1A: std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x404416: std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<float> const&) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x405917: std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::vector(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x40574E: void std::_Construct<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&>(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x405524: std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >* std::__uninitialized_fill_n<false>::__uninit_fill_n<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, unsigned long, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, unsigned long, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x4051ED: std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >* std::uninitialized_fill_n<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, unsigned long, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, unsigned long, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x404DB9: std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >* std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, unsigned long, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, unsigned long, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >&) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505==    by 0x4045B9: std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >::_M_fill_initialize(unsigned long, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&) (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)
==3505== 
==3505== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall writev()
--3505-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--3505-- si_code=128;  Faulting address: 0x0;  sp: 0x802ca9e30

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

host stacktrace:
==3505==    at 0x38091C12: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==3505==    by 0x38050E84: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==3505==    by 0x380510A9: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==3505==    by 0x380D4F7B: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==3505==    by 0x380E3946: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 3505)
==3505==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3505==    by 0x4F5B96C: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char*>(char*, char*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==3505==    by 0x4F5B9CE: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==3505==    by 0x402600: main (in /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o)


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

---

Output, after removing all the successfully printed text:

```
*** Error in `./C3_Boxcar.o': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x00000000010bdcc0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f47235637e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f472356c37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f472357053c]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x40547a]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x405122]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x404c84]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x40447b]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x403b6d]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x40541d]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x405093]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x404baa]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x4043a5]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x4046c4]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x403da4]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x402705]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f472350c830]
./C3_Boxcar.o[0x401859]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00409000 r-xp 00000000 08:13 123604203                          /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o
00608000-00609000 r--p 00008000 08:13 123604203                          /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o
00609000-0060a000 rw-p 00009000 08:13 123604203                          /home/tarun/C3_Boxcar.o
010ab000-0406e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f471c000000-7f471c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f471c021000-7f4720000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f47231e3000-7f47232eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 51122365                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f47232eb000-7f47234ea000 ---p 00108000 08:11 51122365                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f47234ea000-7f47234eb000 r--p 00107000 08:11 51122365                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f47234eb000-7f47234ec000 rw-p 00108000 08:11 51122365                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f47234ec000-7f47236ac000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 51122486                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f47236ac000-7f47238ac000 ---p 001c0000 08:11 51122486                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f47238ac000-7f47238b0000 r--p 001c0000 08:11 51122486                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f47238b0000-7f47238b2000 rw-p 001c4000 08:11 51122486                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f47238b2000-7f47238b6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f47238b6000-7f47238cc000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 51122503                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f47238cc000-7f4723acb000 ---p 00016000 08:11 51122503                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4723acb000-7f4723acc000 rw-p 00015000 08:11 51122503                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4723acc000-7f4723c3e000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 59246590                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f4723c3e000-7f4723e3e000 ---p 00172000 08:11 59246590                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f4723e3e000-7f4723e48000 r--p 00172000 08:11 59246590                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f4723e48000-7f4723e4a000 rw-p 0017c000 08:11 59246590                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f4723e4a000-7f4723e4e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4723e4e000-7f4723e74000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 51118105                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f4723fb3000-7f4724046000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4724070000-7f4724073000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4724073000-7f4724074000 r--p 00025000 08:11 51118105                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f4724074000-7f4724075000 rw-p 00026000 08:11 51118105                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f4724075000-7f4724076000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffafd70000-7fffafd91000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffafd92000-7fffafd94000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fffafd94000-7fffafd96000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
[1]    10287 abort (core dumped)  ./C3_Boxcar.o /home/tarun/Documents/Work/Data/10Dec2019/extract/ML/scaled/C3
```

GDB where output ---

```
0x00007ffff74aa428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
0x00007ffff74ac02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
0x00007ffff74ec7ea in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=2, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7605e98 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
0x00007ffff74f537a in malloc_printerr (ar_ptr=<optimized out>, ptr=<optimized out>, str=0x7ffff7605ff0 "free(): invalid next size (normal)", action=3) at malloc.c:5006
_int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3867
0x00007ffff74f953c in __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:2968
0x000000000040547a in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>::deallocate(float*, unsigned long) ()
0x0000000000405122 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<float> >::deallocate(std::allocator<float>&, float*, unsigned long) ()
0x0000000000404c84 in std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_deallocate(float*, unsigned long) ()
0x000000000040447b in std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >::~_Vector_base() ()
0x0000000000403b6d in std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >::~vector() ()
0x000000000040541d in void std::_Destroy<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*) ()
0x0000000000405093 in void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*>(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*) ()
0x0000000000404baa in void std::_Destroy<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*>(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*) ()
0x00000000004043a5 in void std::_Destroy<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >&) ()
0x00000000004046c4 in std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >::_M_erase_at_end(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >*) ()
0x0000000000403da4 in std::vector<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >::clear() ()
0x0000000000402705 in main ()
```

Comment: You can't assume that a vector of vectors can be flattened to a single `char[]` buffer. Read in a loop.

Comment: I still got proper output, without any issue. @user207421

Comment: Also, [Reading a 2D vector from a binary file](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/58449/)

Comment: The error appears when the vector goes out of scope.

Comment: So you corrupted the vector by doing what I said you can't do. So don't do it. And take notice of the warning you got on `read()`.

Comment: @user207421 [How does a vector store data internally](https://thispointer.com/how-stdvector-works-internally/) _std::vector allocates a memory on heap and store all its elements in contiguous memory location._

Comment: You have a vector of vectors. The elements are vectors themselves.  The outer vector contains vector elements. There is nothing anywhere that says the outer vector's elements constitute a single `char[]` buffer as you are assuming.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Also, could you tell me why it worked, I mean, I got the required output. @user207421